# How to hide the login and register button after user login

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf, web

What I want is to hide the login and register section of the html after user logs in with his account, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the HTML and JavaScript code:

```
<div class="u lf " id="checkviewuser">
  <span>
    <a id="numero2" href="/RIDOApp/login.xhtml">login</a><b> | </b>
    <a id="numero1" href="/RIDOApp/registraction.xhtml">register</a>  
  </span>
</div>

<div class="lf">
  <h:outputText value="&#160;&#160;Welcome Back, #{userBean.firstName} &#160;&#160;" rendered="#{userBean.isLogin}" />
  <p:commandLink value="logout" rendered="#{userBean.isLogin}" action="#{userBeanController.logout}" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  if (('' + #{
      userBean.firstName
    } + 0) == 0) {
    $("#yhzx").hide();
    $("#checkviewuser").show();

  } else {
    $("#yhzx").show();
    $("#checkviewuser").hide();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: 1) I don't see anything with `id="yhzx"` in there. Either there isn't one or you need to include the rest of the html. 2) What specifically isn't working? Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I assume `#{userBean.firstName}` is filled in by a templating engine of some kind, and that it's quoted properly by that engine. Why not just check if it's an empty string? `if (#{userBean.firstName})...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSF Display / Hide div components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749137/jsf-display-hide-div-components)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694450/how-can-i-show-hide-component-with-jsf

Comment: I edited the post and corrected that duplicated `</div>` tag I mentioned above.

Comment: Why don't you just use `rendered="#{not empty userBean.firstName}"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `panelGroup` to wrap all the elements that are not visible when the user is logged in, and use the `rendered` attribute, like you did with the `commandLink` to tell JSF whether to show them or not. No javascript necessary.

Something like this:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not userBean.isLogin}">
    <div class="u lf " id="checkviewuser">
        <span><a id="numero2" href="/RIDOApp/login.xhtml">login</a><b> | </b>
        <a id="numero1" href="/RIDOApp/registraction.xhtml">register</a> </span>
    </div>
</h:panelGroup>
```